# Regular expression for gherkin syntax cucumber

Tags: angularjs, regex, cucumber, cucumberjs, cucumber-java

I want to write a regular expression for input box validation with respect to Gherkin syntax.The valid example inputs are like this
Ex:

```
Given I enter "www.google.com"
And enter keyword "new york"
When I click on "Images"
Then I can see "image list"
```

Basically, I am trying for:   any case(Given|When|And|Then)+String+"String in quotes"

i tried this but not working: (Given|When|And|Then)^[A-Za-z]+$/"(?:[^"\]|\.)*"/

created a form like this

```
<body ng-app="app">
 <form name="exampleForm" class="elegant-aero">
   <label>Test Step:</label>
   <input type="email" name="steps" ng-model="teststeps" ng-pattern="(Given|When|And|Then)^[A-Za-z]+$/"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"/" required/>
   <div ng-messages="exampleForm.steps.$error">
     <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
     <div ng-message="pattern">Must be a valid gherkin syntax</div>
   </div>
 </form>
</body>
```

[CodePenn](http://codepen.io/patilrohan/pen/BjRJLe)

Comment: Is it correct to say you're trying to make a web form to validate gherkin syntax, NOT make use of Gherkin via cucumber?

Comment: yes. Right now I am just making client side validation on front end.

Comment: I think the quoted string should be unwrapped using unroll the loop technque: [`^(Given|When|And|Then)(?:\s+[A-Za-z]+)+\s+"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"$`](https://regex101.com/r/jK6qU8/1). This way it will be more efficient.

Comment: yes this regex seems to be good. But when i use in ng-pattern it doesn't work because of multiple quotes i guess

Comment: You can work around the quotes using `\x22` with `^(Given|When|And|Then)(?:\s+[A-Za-z]+)+\s+\x22[^\x22\\]*(?:\\.[^\x22\\]*)*\x22$`. Also, you have `type="email"` and I think it should be `type="text"`. I added that as an answer since it seems working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
<input type="text" name="steps" ng-model="teststeps" ng-pattern="/^(Given|When|And|Then)(?:\s+[A-Za-z]+)+\s+\x22[^\x22\\]*(?:\\.[^\x22\\]*)*\x22$/" required/>
```

See [updated pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVmxVw)

First, change `type` to `text`. Second, mind that quotes cannot be used as plain or escaped ones, you need to either use `&quot;` or `\x22` in the pattern. Third, the quoted C strings (with escape sequences) are better matched with an unrolled pattern (i.e. `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"`) - it is the most efficient pattern I know for those "..." strings.

Comment: Thank you !! Just Quick modification i faced that If i want to add string after quoted string. Ex. Given If i enter "100" in search box. I tried this Regex but not working :   ^(Given|When|And|Then)(?:\s+[A-Za-z]+)+\s+"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"$\s*(?:\s+[A-Za-z]+)*

Comment: Try `^(Given|When|And|Then)(?:\s+[A-Za-z]+)+\s+\x22[^\x22\\]*(?:\\.[^\x22\\]*)*\x22$`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/fO2kV4/1).

Comment: Thanks. I finally settled up with ^(given|when|and|then)(?:\s+[A-Za-z]+)+\s+\x22[^\x22\\]*(?:\\.[^\x22\\]*)*\x22(?:(\s*[A-Za-z])*)?$    Do you know how to make (Given|when|then|add) case insensitive in regex ?

Comment: To make the pattern case insensitive you can use `/i` modifier: `"/^(Given|When|And|Then)(?:\s+[A-Za-z]+)+\s+\x22[^\x22\\]*(?:\\.[^\x22\\]*)*\x22$/i"`

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, this seems to work, and performs captures of each segment:

`(Given|When|Then|AND)([^"]+)(".+")`

To go a bit further, trying to validate a language with a grammer via a regex embedded in the DOM sounds extremely painful and a bad idea. Especially since Gherkin doesn't really follow the format you suggest in your question.

If you need to do this for some reason, I'd suggest you use the actual gherkin library to parse the string: https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin3